# Limit the [owasp] and [owasp-top-ten] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the following two tags:

- [owasp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owasp), 142 questions
- [owasp-top-ten](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owasp-top-ten), 57 questions

Questions tagged with one or both of these falls in a number of categories:

1. They are about OWASP products, e.g. Zap.
2. They are about the practices of the OWASP organization itself, e.g. criteria for the top ten list.
3. They are about an issue included on the top ten list, such as XSS.
4. The OP came across some OWASP resource while doing research for the question.

To me, #1 and #2 looks like legit reasons to tag but #3 and #4 do not. If they were, every single webapp question could be tagged with [owasp-top-ten](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owasp-top-ten).

So I'd suggest we do something about this tag misuse.  Removing the tags where they do not belong would be a start. Perhaps they should also be merged into one? Or what do you think?

Comment: I may have done a couple just now... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they have to remain separate tags - the OWASP Top Ten is simply one (probably the most well known) of the OWASP activities.

But I agree with you that your cases #3 and #4 would be better off with the tag removed.

As usual, please don't do all at once or a huge number of questions will get bumped to the front page :-)

Comment: agreed, separate tags, but nix #3 and #4

Comment: Ok, will take it easy with the tag removal.

Answer (score 3):

A status update on the progress:

- [owasp-top-ten](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owasp-top-ten) has been cleaned up and is down from 57 to 22 questions.
- [owasp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owasp) has been reduced from 142 to 84 questions. [All but 34](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owasp+-owasp-top-ten+-zap+-webgoat+-esapi+-mod-security+-asvs) are now also tagged with whatever OWASP technology they are about, e.g. ZAP. There is probably still some cleaning that could be done, but the worst is fixed now. I'm calling it a day.